# Jack Daniels - Bottle in the freezer

Tags: whiskey

I have this classic bottle of Jack Daniels, 1 liter. Before serving it, I planned to chill it down a bit in a freezer (-17°C) for couple of hours. 
I know the alcohol freezing point is way below commercial -17°C (1°F), but I wonder is there any chance the bottle might burst inside the freezer?

I had some bursting of the spirits before, though those spirits were lower in the grade.

Comment: out of interest why do you need it that cold?

Comment: The thing is, I dont. I assumed to make it ice cold and serve it like that. But after reading some articles, people advice not to do that, as it kills the flavor. I have moved it to fridge.

Comment: For good whisk(e)y I would advise serving it at room temperature but, since this is just JD, chilling it won't do much damage. are you planning to use it neat or with a mixer? I'd recommend adding ice if its with a mixer instead of chilling as the mixer will take away most of the flavour anyway

Comment: There is a group of people with different taste. Some of them want it with rocks, some with Coke and some neat. I prepared some icecubes, chilled some coke to meet everyones requirements. Do you have any idea how to make it better, in terms of serving or ant other idea?

Comment: I'm the wrong person to ask as I abhor JD since there are much better american whiskies at the same price point without the needless attempts to make a mass produced product sound like a cottage industry.

Comment: I understand, but I am in Germany, and JD is something we can get at decent price. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60568/discussion-between-md-tech-and-vedran-maricevic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting a bottle [Jack Daniels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Daniel%27s) into the freezer for a couple of hours or so should be okay.

> The average home freezer is about -17 C (-1 F). This is cold enough to freeze your food and ice, but **not cold enough to freeze the average bottle of 80-proof liquor.**
>
> Water freezes at 0 C (32 F) and the freezing point of pure ethanol alcohol is -114 C (-173.2 F). Alcoholic beverages are a mixture of both alcohol and water (in some cases, sugars and other additives as well) so the freezing point of your alcoholic beverages is somewhere in between.
>
> The exact freezing point of vodka, tequila, rum, whiskey and liqueurs (as well as wine and beer) is dependent on its alcohol by volume (or its proof).
>
> **The Freezing Temperatures of Alcohol**
>
> 40 Proof Liquor
>   20%: -7 C (22 F) Includes many low-proof liqueurs like Irish cream. If left in a really cold freezer too long, these may get slushy, but this is rare.
>
> 64 Proof Liquor
>   32%: -23 C (-10 F) A liqueur like amaretto and a flavored whiskey like Fireball would fall in this range. These should be okay in the freezer.
>
> 80 Proof Liquor
>   40%: -27 C (-17 F) Includes most standard base liquors like gin, vodka, whiskey, etc. You're clear for the freezer! - [Is Your Beer, Wine, and Liquor Safe in the Freezer?](https://www.thespruce.com/will-liquor-freeze-760302)

Advertisement